# How to reorder columns and make all labels appear?

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have a chart in my SSRS 2008 R2 report:
[image]

I want to reorder these programs in alphabetical order and I want to display all programs.  In the image above, see how only some of the program labels appear?

Here is some sample table data:

```
create table sample_programs
(
program_name varchar(25),
LOS int,
people_id int identity(1,1)
)

insert sample_programs values('transitional living',50),('educational services',65),('Residential Treatment', 77),
('Regular Foster Care', 23)
```

And the SSRS Chart Value expression:

```
=Sum(Fields!program_los.Value) / 
(CountDistinct(Fields!people_id.Value))
```

Where program_name is the Category group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Vertical Axis Properties`, under `Axis Options`, Change the `Interval` to **1** from **Auto**. For reordering the programs, go to the `Category Group Properties`, Under `Sorting`, select the appropriate sort order.